# Why does GetFields() not return anything?

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve the public properties of an object but it is returning nothing.  Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class AdHocCallReportViewModel : ReportViewModel
{
    public string OperatorForCustEquipID { get; set; }
    public string OperatorForPriorityID { get; set; }
    public string OperatorForCallTypeID { get; set; }
    public string OperatorForStatusID { get; set; }
}

public UpdateReportParameters(AdHocCallReportViewModel rvm)
{
    var type = rvm.GetType();
    foreach (var f in type.GetFields().Where(f => f.IsPublic))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(f.GetValue(rvm).ToString());
    }
}
```

When stepping through the code, it skips over the foreach loop because GetFields returns zero items.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You haven't got public fields. They are properties. So try `type.GetProperties()` instead.

Comment: duplicate of my answer so take a +1 =)

Comment: This is dishonestly that author accepted your answer, my answer was given first and it's the same. :(

Comment: It happens a lot with trivial questions and answers like this that get submitted sometimes within seconds of eachother. Nothing to do with dishonesty. Sometimes you're the bug, sometimes you're the wind shield.

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to get fields, you should try to call `GetProperties()`

Answer (score 2):

Pass `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public` to get all instance fields.

On second thought, I'm seeing that you are explicitly filtering for public fields. The class does not have any public fields. The fields that are automatically generated by the compiler as the backing store for the properties are private.

Comment: о_О why you've taken this if you need to get public PROPERTIES, not fields?

Comment: Restuta: You wouldn't do this if you wanted public *properties*. It's not clear what the OP is trying to do. Since he used `GetFields`, I assume he was looking for the fields. Anyway, it should be pointed out that the object *does indeed have fields* but they are private.

Comment: But as the class as implemented by the OP has only properties, it's more likely to assume he is looking for the properties, also because he seems to be looking for the public ones.